# Django multiple one to many join

Tags: python, django, join

I have one to many relationship in many places in my Django app.
For example I have user, home and key:

```
class User(Model):
    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
class Home(Model):
    id_home = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey('user.User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_user_home')
class Key(Model):
    id_key = models.AutoField(primary=True)
    id_home = models.ForeignKey('home.Home', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_home_key')
```

From session I have `user = User(1)` and I want to get all keys for homes of this user.

Comment: You mean `user.key_set.all()`?

Comment: yes, but It don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Key.objects.filter(id_home__id_user=user)`. This creates 2 joins such that `Key x Home x User` and filters on `id_user`.

You can inspect generated sql with:

`print(Key.objects.filter(id_home__id_user=user).query)`

Comment: What if I want to do with 4 or more models?

Comment: @Behoston django orm handles joins via double underscores. If we had another model, say `Family` and had a `ForeignKey` on `User` to family, you would be able to use `Key.objects.filter(id_home__id_user__id_family=family)`

Comment: ;__; It's looking so dirty... I really think about using SQL Alchemy ORM instead Django ORM, Alchemy is much more readable in complex queries and probably give much control with building queries.